# How to generate a bulk wallet offline with python, java or c++?

Tags: address-generation

I want to generate, say 100000 key pairs (address/private key). It should be done offline, without using websites/javascript , with a program on the command line. Of course, the software should use the best way to generate randomness. There is such function on https://www.bitaddress.org , but it's javascript and is not easy to be used by scripts on the command line. Do you know of such software?

Comment: You might want to consider deterministic wallets instead of generating list of keys. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet - this way you could avoid maintaining the list of keys

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case I actually need the list in order to match addresses to users and spend the amounts.

Comment: Well you can always use the user id as the deterministic seed :)

Comment: That would be easily determined ;)

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way is to use [`Vanitygen`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen) with the following command:

```
vanitygen -k -o output.txt -s seeds.txt 1
```

- `-k` keeps it going after it finds a hit
- `-o output.txt` will write the key pairs to the file `output.txt`
- `-s seeds.txt` will let you have different seeds. Create this on beforehand
- `1` is the pattern Vanitygen will look for. Because all addresses start with `1`, every hit will be good. Also nice if you want to have nice addresses, like `1Hristo` or something. Keep in mind that it will reduce speed ALOT.

Vanitygen creates about 300 kKey/second on my 2010 MBP CPU. With `oclvanitygen` it is around 750 kKeys/second. The `output.txt` will reduce the speed a bit, but it will not take a lifetime. I am not on a computer right now on which I can test the command, but it *should* work.

This will generate key pairs until infinity. If you really want to have exactly 1000000 (or any other number) pairs, try something with a bash for-loop, and something like

```
vanitygen 1 >> output.txt
```

Again, I cannot check this right now, so I don't know how the pairs will be in the `output.txt`, but it should be appended and readable for you.

Comment: @HristoHristov Out of curiosity: did you use this? If yes, how fast did it go? Was it with ~ 200kKeys/seconds?

Comment: It's 1.99 Mkey/s for hard prefixes, but in the case with "1" and writing to output.txt, I'm getting 1K keys per second, which is good enough. It's slower of course, because I guess it's faster to discard an invalid key early, instead of completing the calculations for each key. Anyway, it's fast enough for this case.

Comment: That's a slowing factor I didn't expect. For what I understood from vanitygen is that it creates a key, computes the address and checks it. If good, print the key pair and create new pair (with `-k` option). If false, create new key. That printing doesnt cost that much resources I imagined. But thanks for the numbers :)

Comment: That slowdown is not at all surprising to me: printing and writing to a file is expensive business, especially if the app was only expecting to rarely print values. If it were useful, a version of vanitygen (addressgen?) could be created optimized for this use case. But since it's good enough as-is...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bitcoinj](https://bitcoinj.github.io/) — a thoroughly tested Java library written by a google employee as a 20% project. It is used by some wallet apps, such as samurai wallet, bitcoin wallet, greenbits (mycelium plans to migrate to bitcoinj).

1. Clone the project from https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj.git
2. Install [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) if missing (e.g. `brew install maven` on osx or `apt install maven` on linux), and then sync the project so that all dependencies are satisfied: `mvn install` (from the project folder).
3. Use the following code to generate your private/public key pairs.

```
import org.bitcoinj.core.Address;
import org.bitcoinj.core.DumpedPrivateKey;
import org.bitcoinj.core.ECKey;
import org.bitcoinj.core.NetworkParameters;

public class GeneratePrivateKey {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            ECKey key = new ECKey();
            DumpedPrivateKey privKey = key.getPrivateKeyEncoded(NetworkParameters.prodNet());
            System.out.println("private key: " + privKey.toBase58());
            Address pubAddress = new Address(NetworkParameters.prodNet(), key.getPubKeyHash());
            System.out.println("public key: " + pubAddress.toBase58());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```